# update form with 2 parts

Tags: php, mysql

hello everyone I am just starting PHP this year and I try to make form that is content 2 part first part main data second part it content table that I can add new row to enter data and this row content multi-select input and I try many times to write PHP code that I can update this form but I failed every time I try

```
<div class="modal-body">
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="shop_name">اسم المحل:
                                  <a style="color: red">*</a>
                              </label>
                              <div class="col-sm-3">
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="shop_name" value="<?php echo $strshop; ?>" name="shop_name" placeholder="اسم المحل" data-index="8">
                              </div>
                              <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="cus_name">اسم العميل:
                              </label>
                              <div class="col-sm-3">
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="cus_name" name="cus_name" value="<?php echo $strcus; ?>" placeholder="اسمع العميل" data-index="9">
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="cus_address">العنوان:<a style="color: red">*</a></label>
                              <div class="col-sm-3">
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="cus_address" name="cus_address" value="<?php echo $straddres; ?>" placeholder="عنوان" data-index="10">
                              </div>
                              <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="tel"> التليفون:</label>
                              <div class="col-sm-3">
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="tel" name="tel" value="<?php echo $strtel; ?>" placeholder="تليفون" data-index="11">
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="modal-footer">
                          <h2>مياه</h2>
                          <div class="row clearfix">
                              <div class="col-md-12 column">
                                  <?php
                                  if (!empty($strid)) {
                                  $q2 = "SELECT * FROM product_table WHERE form_id = $strid;";
                                  $result = mysqli_query($con, $q2);
                                  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                                  ?>
                                  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="data_table">
                                      <thead>
                                      <tr>
                                          <th class="text-center">
                                              المنتج
                                          </th>
                                          <th class="text-center">
                                              SKus
                                          </th>
                                          <th class="text-center">
                                              الكمية
                                          </th>
                                          <th class="text-center">
                                              ثلاجات
                                          </th>
                                          <th class="text-center">
                                                            مواد دعائية
                                          </th>
                                          <th class="text-center">
                                              كمية الدعايه
                                          </th>
                                          <th>
                                              action
                                          </th>
                                      </tr>
                                      </thead>
                                      <tbody>
                                      <?php
                                      if ($count > 0) {
                                          while ($wrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                              ?>
                                              <tr id='row'>
                                                  <td>
                                                      <input hidden name="wid" value="<?php echo $wrow['id'] ?>">
                                                      <select class="form-control" id="product_name" name="product_name[]" data-index="12">
                                                          <option selected disabled hidden>اختار المنتج .....</option>
                                                          <?php
                                                          $select_water = $con->query("select * from water");
                                                          if ($select_water->num_rows > 0) {
                                                              // output data of each row
                                                              while ($w = $select_water->fetch_assoc()) {
                                                                  ?>
                                                                  <option <?php if ($wrow['product_name'] == $w['water_name']) echo "selected";?> ><?php echo $w['water_name']?></option>
                                                                  <?php
                                                              }
                                                          } else {
                                                              echo "0 results";
                                                          }
                                                          ?>
                                                      </select>
                                                  </td>
                                                  <td>
                                                      <select class="form-control" id="sk" name="sk[]"
                                                              data-index="6">
                                                          <option selected disabled hidden>اختار Skus</option>
                                                          <?php
                                                          $select_area = $con->query("select * from watersk");
                                                          if ($select_area->num_rows > 0) {
                                                              // output data of each row
                                                              while ($row2 = $select_area->fetch_assoc()) {
                                                                  ?>
                                                                  <option <?php if ($wrow['sk'] == $row2['sk_name']) echo "selected"; ?> ><?php echo $row2 ['sk_name'] ?></option>
                                                                  <?php
                                                              }
                                                          } else {
                                                              echo "0 results";
                                                          }
                                                          ?>
                                                      </select>
                                                  </td>
                                                  <td>
                                                      <input type="number" id="qty" name="qty[]" value="<?php echo $wrow['qty']; ?>" placeholder='الكميه' class="form-control" data-index="16"/>
                                                  </td>
                                                  <td>
                                                      <input type="number" id="friz" name="friz[]" value="<?php echo $wrow['frizer']; ?>" placeholder='ثلاجه' class="form-control" data-index="17"/>
                                                  </td>

                                                  <td>
                                                      <?php
                                                      //                                                                       var_dump($row['id']);
                                                      $water_id = $wrow['id'];
                                                      $test_array=array();
                                                      $select_water_market = $con->query("SELECT * FROM product_market WHERE water_id = $water_id;");
                                                      while ($row3 = $select_water_market->fetch_assoc()) {
                                                          $test_array[]= $row3['watermarket_media'];
                                                      }
                                                      //                                                                       var_dump($test_array);
                                                      ?>
                                                      <select multiple class="form-control" id="market_medi" name="market_media[0][]" data-index="6">
                                                          <?php
                                                          $select_media = $con->query("select * from market_media");
                                                          if ($select_media->num_rows > 0) {
                                                              // output data of each row
                                                              while ($row = $select_media->fetch_assoc()) {
                                                                  ?>
                                                                  <?php if(in_array($row['media_name'],$test_array)){?>
                                                                      <option selected>
                                                                          <?php echo $row ['media_name'] ?>
                                                                      </option>
                                                                      <?php
                                                                  }
                                                                  else
                                                                  {?>
                                                                      <option>
                                                                          <?php echo $row ['media_name'] ?>
                                                                      </option>

                                                                  <?php }
                                                              }
                                                          }else {
                                                              echo "0 results";
                                                          }
                                                          ?>
                                                      </select>
                                                  </td>
                                                  <td>
                                                      <input style="float: right" type="number" id="market"  name="market[]" placeholder="مواد دعائيه"  class="form-control" value="<?php echo $wrow['mark_qty']; ?>" data-index="18"/>
                                                  </td>
                                                  <td>
                                                      <a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" href='save/deleterow.php?id=".$delete['id']." data-toggle="modal"  style="float: left;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
                                                      <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href='save/deleterow.php?id=<?php echo $wrow['id'];?>&stid=<?php echo $strid;?>' data-toggle="modal"  style="float: left;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                                                  </td>

                                              </tr>
                                              <?php
                                          }
                                      }
                                      }
                                      ?>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="" data-toggle="modal" onclick="addVariablesRow();" style="float: left;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <script>

                                        function deleterow2(o) {
                                            //no clue what to put here?
                                            var p = o.parentNode.parentNode;
                                            p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
                                        }
                                        var i = 1;
                                        function addVariablesRow() {
                                            var $t = $("#data_table");
                                            var $row = $t.find("tbody tr").first();
                                            var $r = $row.clone();
                                            $r.attr('id', 'rrow' + i);
                                            var $newRow = $r.find('input').val('').end().append("<td><a  class='btn btn-danger btn-sm delete' onclick='deleterow2(this);'  style='float: left;'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a></td>");
                                            $newRow.appendTo($t).show();
                                            $("#data_table tr:last td:first select").focus();
                                            $('#market_medi').each(function () {
                                                $(this).attr('name', 'market_media[' + i + '][]');
                                            });

                                            i++;

                                        }
                                    </script>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: To make this a good Stack Overflow question, cut down on how much code you're showing: Focus on the important parts directly related to your problem. There's a ton of stuff in here, including some mysterious and presumably irrelevant JavaScript.

Comment: @tedman my problem related to this code already

Comment: There is too much code. **Trim it down**. Include only the portions directly relevant to your problem.